# Why did cargo vendor fail to write the checksum for a crate in a Git repository?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a Rust project where I vendor my dependencies. This is what my `.cargo/config.toml` looks like:

```
# Vendor dependencies from crates.io (but do not check them into Git.)
[source.crates-io]
replace-with = "vendored-sources"

[source.vendored-sources]
directory = "vendor"
```

After some time, I added a Rust crate in a GitHub repository (not crates.io) to my Cargo.toml, which now has a section that looks like:

```
[dependencies.symphonia]
git = "https://github.com/neocrym-forks/Symphonia"
rev = "2cafae82b664ceb14dd5d058f534574399764165"
```

But now when I run the command `cargo vendor --versioned-dirs --quiet`, I get the following error message:

```
error: failed to sync

Caused by:
  failed to write `vendor/symphonia-0.3.0/.cargo-checksum.json`
```

What went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

#### tl;dr: Set your `$CARGO_HOME` to a directory that you can write to.

The `failed to write` error is happening because Cargo cannot find where it "git cloned" the repository from GitHub. Normally, those repositories are cloned to `$CARGO_HOME/git/checkouts` and then are copied to the vendor directory.

In my case, I was using a CI image that was confused about the correct value of `$CARGO_HOME` because Rust was installed by the root user in a location not writeable by the non-root CI user.

I reset my `$CARGO_HOME` to a directory that my non-root user can write to, and it worked.